# Any react-native library for AES 128 encryption with Initial vector?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for any react native library that can be used for the AES 128 encryption. Something like:

crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv[, options]) in Node

I've only found react-native-aes but that's for 256 encryption, not 128

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this library: https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js

It's 100% javascript so It's compatible with react-native aswell.

This library has many encryptions options so I hope it can be helpful for someone else in the future ;)

Comment: But isn't it slow? It's only in JS, so it doesn't use native crypto modules.

Comment: Can you share your example code of this library?